# Dependency version should be updated

Tags: gradle

I have the following dependency in my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0'
```

Debug version of my app builds successfully, but the release version fails to build with the following error:

```
build.gradle:21: Error: mobileads version should be updated to 6.2.0 [MobileAdsSdkOutdatedVersion]
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0'
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Explanation for issues of type "MobileAdsSdkOutdatedVersion":
This is necessary to ensure the proper integration of the Yandex Mobile
Ads. The app can crash if you use an incorrect version.

Vendor: Yandex

1 errors, 0 warnings
```

If I simply change the version with 6.2:

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:6.2'
```

my Java source code that uses this SDK stops compiling, but they (Yandex) do not have a documentation on version 6.2 yet, and their support sends me links to the documentation on version 5.10, so it is not clear enough how to fix compiler errors in Java code.

Is it possible to disable this `issues of type "MobileAdsSdkOutdatedVersion"` and build the release version with `com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0`?

So I'll probably continue using `5.10.0` until they do not update their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their 5.10.0 documentation page says this is documentation about an archived version and links to the documentation of version 6.1.0 which hopefully is close enough for you to progress, so refer to https://yandex.ru/support2/mobile-ads/en/dev/android/release/6-0-0-migration for upgrade instructions.