# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin, its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I [updated an SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523584/dependency-version-should-be-updated) in my Android app from

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0'
implementation 'com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-admob:22.1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-google:22.4.0.0'
```

in my `build.gradle`, and got the following errors:

```
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/dmitr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

Does it mean that I need a newer Java version?

Now my Java version is probably 1.8, at least I have the following in `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and build the project with Java from `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin`:

```
javac --version
javac 17.0.6
```

Comment: This answer might resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/7805359

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle file containing the kotlin version ?

Comment: @NazariiMoshenskiy, yes adding `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'` helped.

Comment: @ItzDavi There was nothing related to Kotlin in my `build.gradle`, but adding `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'` helped.